# How to access attributes of custom components in react native expo cli

Tags: react-native, expo

I created a button component in new file and imported it to my main file and called it as . I want to access attributes and styles such as onClick function of button component from my main file.

```
//Separate custom component

import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default function home(){
    return(
        <View >
            <Pressable>
                <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <Text style = {styles.buttonTitle}>Sign in</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Pressable>
        </View>
    )
}


------------------------------------------------------------------

//Main file

import  ButtonComponent from "../components/button_component";

export default function home(){
    return(
        <View style = {styles.homeContainer}>
            <Text style = {styles.head}>Book App Login</Text>
            <View style = {styles.buttonComponent}>
                <ButtonComponent/>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

So from what I can see, your separate component is also called `home` right now and should be named `button_component` so you can import is as `ButtonComponent`.

Change:

```
export default function home(){
```

to

```
export default function button_component(){
```

As far as how to access the attributes in a custom component - you don't. You include them inside of the custom button component.

So if I wanted to put an onPress print "hello" I would include it in the custom component.

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, Pressable, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';

export default function home(){
    return(
        <View >
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={console.log("Hello}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Sign in</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
```

And when I add that custom component to a new file, the custom component prop will not needed to be added to the new page - it inherits it.

**Also side note - the style is usually typed style={styles.something} without the spaces and you also do not have a stylesheet on either page so it wouldn't be able to find "styles.something" unless you just didn't include it.

**You also don't need to wrap TouchableOpacity in a Pressable. :) You can just use TouchableOpacity alone.

Comment: Ok I changed it to the buttoncomponent. Now how do I access the attributes.?

Comment: So all of your props will stay in the custom component. 
I am not sure why you want to keep one button separate - I believe it would be much easier to have the button and props directly on one page since the page is pretty simple.

Comment: You can find all the props that TouchableOpacity inherits from Pressable here: 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/pressable

Comment: I edited my answer instead of explaining it here in the comments.